# Doing the same exercise but using a function calling

Tags: c

I have a bit of trouble (it's silly i know) when doing an exercise using the function callings so i need some help with "transforming" it.

I have already tested the code and it works i just need to transfer it so when where i have written "All is ok" the function should return +1 and if even one "ERROR" exists(it does or its deliberate) the function should return 0

Edit: Just in case i wasnt clear on what i was asking. All i need is for this code in stead of the coding happening on the main function it needs to happen at another function and then we call that function. I just need some help on how to call this particular function(silly as it is)

Basically for those that might need more info. The exercise is:

We read some telephone numbers written in a certain way. If they are ok the function should return +1 else it should only return 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define M 14
#define N 4
int isValid(char listOfNumbers[][M], int n);
int main()
{

char v[N][M];
FILE*file;
int i;
int c=0;
file=fopen("file","r");
if(file==NULL)
{
    printf("Error in the file____");
    exit(1);
}
if(file==NULL)
{
    printf("Error in the file____");
    exit(1);
}
for(i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    fscanf(file,"%s",&v[i]);
}
for(i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    printf("%s\n",v[i]);

}
isValid(v[N][M],N);
return 0;
}
int isValid(char listOfNumbers[][M], int n)
{

char v[N][M];
FILE*file;
int i,j;
i=0;
j=0;
while(i<N&&j<M)
{
    if(v[i][j]=='(')
    {
        count_brackets[i]++;
        pos1[i]=j;
        j++;
    }
    if(v[i][j]==')')
    {
        count_brackets[i]--;
        pos2[i]=j;
        j++;
    }
    if(v[i][j]=='-')
    {
        count_dash[i]++;
        j++;
    }
    if(isdigit(v[i][j]))
    {
        count_digit[i]++;
    }
    j++;
    if(j==M)
    {
        j=0;
        i++;
    }
}
for(i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    if(count_brackets[i]+count_dash[i]+count_digit[i]==11)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

}

Also if possible just for future use. How do i paste the code i have done(i use codeblocks) in such a way that i dont have to put 4 spaces manually on each line?

Comment: To me it's unclear what is causing troubles. I don't see any attempt to implement nor call the function.

Comment: @4386427 Yeah thats the thing. The code itself works. As i told you. The exercise requrires that we use a function to do what i did in the main. In the case it works the function should return +1, if even one error(there is one intentionally) it should return 0. I am not clear on how to do this. THats what im asking

Comment: yes but ... what is your problem with turning this into a function? what have you tried and what went wrong? You already have the function prototype so what is the problem?

Comment: Well. I copy-pasted this on the function and called it but it always returns 0 no matter what. I literally copy pasted the code into the function and changed the prints in the last if statements into "if everything is ok" return 1 and at else "break and return 0". But its always returning 0

Comment: BTW: I doubt your code is correct but since I don't know how the input file looks I can't say for sure.... in any case your code will fail big time if the input file contains unexpected data

Comment: you should show what you tried... we can't tell what is wrong if you don't tell what you do

Comment: @4386427 The code is absolutely ok i tested it and it works. I just need this

Comment: Then show us how you did it... post the function you wrote and post how you called it. How do you expect us to tell what is wrong when you don't post the code

Comment: @4386427 I edited it. At this point i was just trying random stuff to see if it works

Comment: First bug: `char v[N][M];` inside the function is wrong... use `listOfNumbers` instead of `v`

Comment: Second bug: You shall read the file in `main` and then call the function...

Comment: @4386427 Yeah i changed that.

Comment: okay... as no answer has been posted, you can update your code to what you currently have...

Comment: Well now its returning -1073741819 which most deffinitely means error tho i dont get why

Comment: `isValid(v[N][M],N);` shall be `isValid(v, N);` Didn't your compile give you warnings?

Comment: And again.... Don't do `char v[N][M];` inside the function is wrong... use `listOfNumbers` instead of `v`

Comment: @4386427 Yeah. Give me some time to fix the minor stuff and ill come back if there is a problem.

Comment: And don't do `FILE*file;` inside the function. You don't want a file in the function

Comment: You can present C code in a question or answer by preceding it with a line `\`\`\`c` and following it with a line `\`\`\``.  The `c` is optional; it will probably be inferred if the question is tagged with C ([tag:c]).  Or you can indent all the code by selecting it and using the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent the code, or by using control-K.

Comment: As it stands, the `return 0;` in your function is dead code, never reached because of the `break;` immediately before it.  The `break;` probably isn't wanted; it prevents the code from testing more than the first entry (so the whole `else` clause needs deleting).  The `return 0;` should be outside the loop so it is only executed if all the tests are successful.